# Read block Text of a text file python

Tags: python, file, text, block

**Input File - input.csv**

```
#######A Result:#########
2016-07-27   bar       51     14
2015-06-27   roujri    30     86
#######B Result:#########
2016-08-26   foo       34      83
2016-08-26   foo       34      83
#########################
```

**Output result**

```
A result:
     Col-1: 81
     Col-2: 100
B result:
     Col-1: 68
     Col-2: 166
```

I am trying to solve one problem according to above input, output. So far I can read only first block Text. I want to more generic function so possibly I will only initialise the variable that need to read within the block, not hard coding (e.g. `#######A Result:#########`) and furthermore pass the block info to another function that will sum up the value. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate. Thanks :)

```
import re
def reading_block_text_file(infile):
     with open(infile) as fp:
         for result in re.findall('#######A Result:#########(.*?)#######B Result:#########', fp.read(), re.S):
             print result,

reading_block_text_file(input_file)
```

Comment: That input file doesn't look like CSV to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw in a little bit of regex:

```
$ cat a
#######A Result:#########
2016-07-27   bar       51     14
2015-06-27   roujri    30     86
#######B Result:#########
2016-08-26   foo       34      83
2016-08-26   foo       34      83
#########################
$ cat a.py
import re
col_names = ['abc', 'xyz']
with open("/tmp/a", "r") as f:
    tables = re.findall(r'#+(\w+ Result:)#+([^#]*)', f.read(), re.S)
    for table in tables:
        name = table[0]
        rows = table[1].strip().split('\n')
        print name
        for i in range(len(col_names)):
            print "\t{}: {}".format(col_names[i], sum(map(lambda x: int(x.split()[i + 2]), rows)))
$ python a.py
A Result:
    abc: 81
    xyz: 100
B Result:
    abc: 68
    xyz: 166
```

Regex Explanation:

```
#+(\w+ Result:)#+([^#]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Bito9rGLY6SLIMCx)

Comment: If I defined a list words = ['aba', 'xyz','foo', 'bar'] and instead of Col- take each list value at a time how I can do this ? Thank you for above solution.

Comment: @Roujri Show an example. What do those words represent?

Comment: Words are predefine text retrieve from list - words = ['aba', 'xyz','foo', 'bar']
A Result:
    aba: 81
    xyz: 100
B Result:
    aba: 68
    xyz-2: 166